# PHP imap_search INBOX/SENT ITEMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, imap

I need to search both `Inbox` and `Sent Items` with some criteria.

Assume that the Email Id that i need to filter is `user@example.com`

1. Search in `INBOX` - `FROM`,`CC` field
2. Search in `Sent Items` - `To` field

   $result= imap_search($conn, 'From "user@example.com" To "user@example.com"');

I tried `imap_search` but its not working with multiple criteria.

Also is it posible to search both `INBOX`  and `Sent Items` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Its not Possible

PHP uses Mark Crispin's c-client library under the hood to do its IMAP work. In the c-client library, there is a deprecated method mail_criteria in mail.c that translates an IMAP search string to a c-client search program. mail_criteria has been deprecated for the past 8 years or so and, as such, was never updated to support the IMAP4 search syntax. So search terms like OR that weren't present in IMAP2 never got support in the mail_criteria function. Here's all the terms it supports starting with an 'O':

```
case 'O':                 /* possible OLD, ON */
    if (!strcmp (criterion+1,"LD")) f = pgm->old = T;
    else if (!strcmp (criterion+1,"N"))
      f = mail_criteria_date (&pgm->on,&r);
    break;
```

OR isn't on that list. So even though the c-client supports OR in its SEARCHPGM structs, it doesn't parse OR in the deprecated mail_criteria function.

And PHP still uses mail_criteria to parse search queries. In 2011. So until either the c-client library un-deprecates mail_criteria and makes it IMAP4-compliant or PHP writes its own IMAP search parser, you are stuck with whatever IMAP2 supported. Which doesn't include OR.

imap_search will not working with multiple criteria

Comment: Use loop. Search them and put result in array

Comment: why put all in Query, Sow result for Inbox and put links for Other folders in Result. When user click on That folders like Outfox, Trigger query for that and show result :)